# Running x11 on Mac OS

Tags: c++, x11

I have properly installed the `XQuarts.app` but have the linking phase problem. 
 
Here is the simple code.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>

int main() {
    Display* dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile it from XQuartz.app like this

> g++ -c main.cpp -I/opt/X11/include

However it outputs:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_XOpenDisplay", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [default] Error 1

My mac version:

> Yosemite 10.10.2

I googled a lot but couldn't find any useful help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/include` is for compilation, not linking. You'd find the .h files there, not the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't linking against libX11. Add the following flags to the linker command:

```
-L/opt/X11/lib -lX11
```

Not critical, but worth noting: You do not need to use xterm (the terminal in XQuartz) to build or run X11 applications.

Comment: It works. Can you elaborate more about "Why" this works ? It would be extremely helpful.

Comment: The `XOpenDisplay` function is part of libX11. If you don't link against that library, the linker has nowhere to get that function from.

Comment: And why doesn't this line of code `#include <X11/Xlib.h>` automatically induces compiler to link this library ?

Comment: Because that's not how compilers work. An `#include` gives instructions to the preprocessor; linker flags are used at a much later stage.

Comment: @duskwuff For what it's worth, MSVC provides a `#pragma lib` that embeds a library name in compiled object files that then gets added to the libraries specified on the linker command line.  Though personally, I've usually found that to be more of a misfeature than a feature...